Solving $\tan(3\theta)=\cot(-\theta)$
This is from a trig book called "Trigonometry - A Complete Introduction" by Hugh Neill, in a chapter called "General solutions of equations", where it talks about three of them (they all work in degrees, too; $n$ is an integer):
$$
\begin{align*}
\sin(\theta) &= \sin(x) \implies \theta = \pi n + (-1)^n x \tag{1} \\
\cos(\theta) &= \cos(x) \implies \theta = 2\pi n \pm x \tag{2} \\
\tan(\theta) &= \tan(x) \implies \theta = \pi n + x \tag{3}
\end{align*}
$$
They're different from the ones I've seen generally, but they kinda make sense.
Anyway, here's my current problem: give the general solution (using those three above), in radians, of the following equation: $\tan(3x) = \cot(-x)$.
My attempt:
$$
\begin{align*}
\tan(3x) &= \cot(-x) \tag{1} \\
\tan(3x) &= -\cot(x) \tag{2} \\
\frac{\sin(3x)}{\cos(3x)} &= -\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} \tag{3} \\
\sin(3x) \sin(x) &= -\cos(3x) \cos(x) \tag{4} \\
\sin(3x) \sin(x) + \cos(3x) \cos(x) &= 0 \tag{5} \\
\cos(3x - x) &= 0 \tag{6} \\
\cos(2x) &= 0 \tag{7}
\end{align*}
$$
This means the primary angle is $\pi/2$ (or 90°).
Now applying the above general formula for cosine (general formula (2)), we get:
$$
2x = 2\pi n ± \pi/2 \\
x = \pi n ± \pi/4
$$
However, the book gives this answer: $\pi n/2 + \pi/4$
I have no idea how. This is the 17th exercise, so I did manage to solve some, but this one stumped me.
Note, too, that there's no $\pm$ in their answer, just +. It maybe has to do with something that I've yet to grasp: the fact the the author sometimes distinguishes between negative and positive $n$, when solving an equation. I've no idea why he chooses to do that.
For example, for $2x = 360n \pm (90 - x)$, he gives two solutions, by first taking the positive sign of $n$, then the negative. No idea when or why that's done. The book is frustratingly terse sometimes. Anyway, I thought to mention this, as it might have something to do with the answer.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

$\cos(3\pi/2)=0,$ also. The zeros of $\cos$ come in period $\pi,$ not $2\pi.$

Thanks. But I'm not sure I follow. The general formula usually asks you to plug in the primary angle, which, for cos(x)=0, it's /2. Even if I do 2x = 2n ± 3/2, I still can't reach the book's answer. Can you please expand on your suggestion?

The general formula is that there are two values such that $\cos x=a$ for $a\in(-1,1).$

If cos(2x) = 0 then the general solution is x = π/4 + Kπ/2 for any integer K. So I don't understand the claim "cos(2x) = 0. This means the primary angle is π/2".  But my lack of understanding might be because you have not defined what you mean by "primary angle".

Saying it works on both radians and degrees is like saying it works in kilometers and miles. Of course it does.

Both of you are correct. Note that for every solution of yours, there is a corresponding solution of the book's and vice versa. Your solution is written with a $\pm$, they converted it into one without it.
You can fix the problem right at the root. The book tells you that $$\cos(\theta)=\cos(\pi/2)\Rightarrow \theta=2\pi n\pm \pi/2$$ Take it as an exercise to show that at the level of sets $$\{2\pi n\pm \pi/2\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}=\{\pi m+\pi/2\mid m\in\mathbb Z\}$$ Write down a few values on both sides and try to find a pattern.
Then note that if you use the new expression, you get the result of the book.

More simply, recall that for $x\neq n\frac \pi 2$ and $y\neq m\pi $
$$\tan x=\cot y \iff y=\frac \pi 2-x +k\pi\tag 1$$
with $n,m,k \in\mathbb Z$ then
$$\tan (3\theta)=\cot (-\theta)\iff -\theta=\frac \pi 2-3\theta+k\pi \iff \boxed{\theta =\frac \pi 4 +k\frac \pi 2} $$
which is equivalent to $\boxed{\theta=\pm\frac \pi 4 +k \pi }$.

For identity $(1)$ refer to definition of $\tan$ and $\cot$ according to the following sketch


To better understand the equivalence of the two solutions maybe also the following sketch may help


We have $\tan(3x)-\cot(-x)=\tan(3x)+\cot(x)=0$ then
$$\frac{3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)}{4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)}+\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=0$$ which using $\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)$ reduces to $$\frac{-1+2\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)(4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x))}=0$$
Thus $\cos(x)=\pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}$ and since we must have the denominator $\sin(x)(4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x))\ne0$ $$\boxed{x=\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{4}\space,\hspace0.5cm n\in\mathbb Z}$$


we get: n ± /4
However, the book gives this answer: n/2 + /4

Factor out $\dfrac{\pi}4$ from the two solutions, then observe that
$$\left\{4n\pm1\mid n\in\mathbb Z\right\}=\left\{\ldots,-1,1,3,5,7,8,\ldots\right\}=\left\{2n+1\mid n\in\mathbb Z\right\}.$$

$$
\begin{align*}
\sin(\theta) &= \sin(x) \color\red{\iff} \theta = \pi n + (-1)^n x \tag{1} \\
\cos(\theta) &= \cos(x) \color\red{\iff} \theta = 2\pi n \pm x \tag{2} \\
\tan(\theta) &= \tan(x) \color\red{\iff} \theta = \pi n + x \tag{3}
\end{align*}
$$
These general solutions are different from the ones I've seen generally, but they kinda make sense.

Yes, and the general solutions that you're referring to, like
$$\tan(\theta) = k \iff \theta = \pi n + \arcsin(k),$$ can be derived from the above lot, which is more general.

$$
\begin{align*}
\cos(2x) &= 0 \tag{7}
\end{align*}
$$
This means the primary angle is /2.

Does "primary angle" mean "basic angle"/"reference angle" (the acute angle between the x-axis and the terminal arm) or principal angle? The former is not generally correct! For example, $$\tan(\theta)=-1$$ has solution $(\pi n\color\red{-\frac{\pi}4})$ (using the principal angle, or any solution, really) rather than $(\pi n\color\red{+\frac{\pi}4})$ (using the acute, "basic angle").

I can't hold back at a very weird way of solving this and directly getting the book's result! It might not be fully rigorous mind you, but it's fun (I did not want to edit my original answer because this is something the OP might not be familiar with, but someone else might appreciate it, maybe even OP. Since it's just a fun thing, I will make it community wiki).
Okay here goes. We have $$\tan(3x)=\cot(-x)=-\cot(x)$$ and thus $$\tan(3x)\tan(x)=-1$$ By the $\tan$ angle sum formula, we know that $$\tan(a-b)=\frac{\tan(a)-\tan(b)}{1+\tan(a)\tan(b)}$$ if we plug in $a=3x$ and $b=x$, the LHS is $\tan(2x)$ whereas the right side is just infinity. But $\tan(\pi/2)$ is also infinity (very questionable, but "insert argument making it rigorous") and thus we can place $$\tan(2x)=\tan(\pi/2)$$ Using OP's mentioned results, one gets $$2x=\pi n+\pi/2$$ Dividing by $2$ throughout, we finally arrive at $x=\pi n/2+\pi/4$.
I am open to making this more rigorous! That "replcing infinity" step seems so shady at best and wrong at worst, but this somehow works.

Why don't use, from here $\tan(3x)\tan(x)=-1$ product to sum formula? by this  way we reduce to $\cos (2x)=0$.

Oh we can! I just wanted to know why the way I did here works, because I can't really find a proper justification

Anyway a simple use of symmetry solve easily the problem. Best way in my opinion.

It looks really a border line solution to me!
